# Calculating Mean of Subset of Rows for all Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate statistics on a column by filtering out rows that do not pass a flag, but returning the overall statistic for all rows.  The concept is essentially using an 'estimation universe' to calculate the statistics.  My actual example is much more complex, so I simplified to a basic example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = range(0,20)
data = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(20),index = idx)
flag = pd.Series(np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),index = idx)
```

With the data above, I want to return the mean of data, but only calculating the mean for rows where flag == 1.  The challenge I'm having is returning the mean for all rows, even the ones that are not used to calculate it.

I could do something like this:

```
data.groupby(flag).mean()
```

And then repeat the value for the 1 group across all rows, however this won't work because my example uses an additional layer of groups to calculate statistics.  In my real example, I am basically calculating the group mean and standard deviation for each row using a separate grouping, but I also want those statistics to only be calculated using rows that pass the flag.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

In response to the first comment, here is what I would expect the output to look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

idx = range(0,20)
data = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(20),index = idx)
flag = pd.Series(np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),index = idx)
```

I'm looking for the mean of group 1:

```
data.groupby(flag).mean()

0    0.466647
1    0.442576
dtype: float64
```

And then to have it repeated for every row:

```
pd.Series(data.groupby(flag).mean()[1],index = idx)

0     0.442576
1     0.442576
2     0.442576
3     0.442576
4     0.442576
5     0.442576
6     0.442576
7     0.442576
8     0.442576
9     0.442576
10    0.442576
11    0.442576
12    0.442576
13    0.442576
14    0.442576
15    0.442576
16    0.442576
17    0.442576
18    0.442576
19    0.442576
dtype: float64er code here
```

I'm just looking for a better way to do this, because ultimately this is going to scale to several statistics across many datasets and will involve additional layers of grouping.

Hope that's clear.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm still just a little unclear. You're working with `Series`. You could set a whole column of a frame to a constant quite easily `df['avg'] = data[flag.eq(1)].mean()`. Otherwise the series has to look like `pd.Series(data[flag.eq(1)].mean(), index=idx)`. The `groupby` is unnecessary in this instance. But I have concern that in simplifying the data, you've also underrepresented the problem.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.  You are right I am completely under-representing the full problem, but I think the .eq method is exactly what I need here for the first step.  I will work with this for now.